# &str with lifetime for "After Deserialization"

Tags: rust, lifetime

I'm beating my head on lifetimes and `&str`.

I have a bunch of strings in my program that aren't actually static, but come close: they're loaded from a json at initialization, and should remain in scope for the entire length of the program.

I have a bunch of structs that use these. I would like to get away with just having `&strs` in those structs, for `Copy`, etc. I can do this by having lots of lifetime parameters, but those propagate everywhere and every time I've used them they've been a mistake. On the other hand, I don't want to flood my code with `.to_owned()`s and `.clone()`s either, when it's always the same strings and they're never mutated.

I can *almost* say these are `& 'static str` stings, but I don't think that's quite true and I haven't found a way to do so. However, they'd come out of "initialization" functions at the start of the program, and remain in scope past the end.

This mirrors a problem I've had in general - wanting references that refer to something whose lifetime is "long" in some sense (longer than an associated type is used for, or longer than *all* of the invocations of some function).

One way I can see to do this is to have a `'program` lifetime that goes on basically everything, and try to maintain that that parameter always refers to the actual lifetime of the (post-initialization) program. That sounds like it's going to be a lot of boiler plate and get me int trouble down the line, though.

What would be truly ideal would be to have lifetime parameters on the module level - basically say that for *everything* from a given module, certain things stay in scope. I don't think there's any way to do that, is there?

Is there a better way to do this? Or a way to take a String that comes out of some arbitrary function and get a valid `'static` reference to it?

Comment: You can store the actual strings in some `static` item and refer to it.

Comment: Lifetime taint is something you'll just have to deal with. The good news is that it doesn't necessarily impact any code using these structures, you can often omit lifetime values if they can be defaulted or assumed.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Okay, that makes sense - so have a `static Vec<String>` or something, fill it during initialization, and then point everything at that?

Comment: How can anything in a module stay in scope? Unless it's `static` that's not a reasonable expectation.

Comment: @tadman So in my head I'm thinking of it as being like a sub-program - I have my "initialization" code and then my "runtime" code, and it would be nice if I could treat the entirety of "runtime" as a run from the perspective of which things defined in "initialization" are static. (I get that I'm mixing concepts here, this isn't really a namespace consideration, but it would be the easiest way to organize it.)

Comment: I mean you can think of it that way, but Rust sure doesn't.

Comment: You may want to look at how some [existing projects](https://github.com/google/zerocopy) deal with this. A lot of it involves carefully considering which lifetimes you need, and making a lot of those "automatic" as in Rust can figure it out based on arguments. For example, given an X reference, return a reference to a subset of X data with the same lifetime.

Comment: Your initial usecase sounds a lot like you just want [`Box::leak`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/boxed/struct.Box.html#method.leak) to just give you static references.

Comment: Sounds like a use for [OnceCell and OnceLock](https://blog.rust-lang.org/2023/06/01/Rust-1.70.0.html#oncecell-and-oncelock)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your usecase seems like a perfect fit for the `lazy_static` crate, or the `once_cell` crate/standard library api (more on this later).

The basic use of [lazy cell](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.LazyCell.html), is

```rust
#![feature(lazy_cell)]

use std::sync::LazyLock;
use rand;

static LAZY: LazyLock<String> = LazyLock::new(|| {
    rand::random::<f64>().to_string() // <-- pretend this loads json
});

fn main() {
    println!("{}", *LAZY);
    let lazy_ref: &'static str = &*LAZY;
    println!("{}", lazy_ref);
}
```

You'll notice the `feature` attribute at the top of the code. This only works in nightly rust, but it is heavily based on an existing crate that works in stable, called [once_cell](https://docs.rs/once_cell/latest/once_cell/sync/struct.Lazy.html) (replace the `use` with `once_cell::sync::Lazy`). `lazy_static` works similarly, but uses a macro and won't be included in the standard library, so I chose to show how to use `LazyLock` instead.

You want to read and parse all your json at once, as re-parsing the json for every setting would be very slow. I think your best option is to parse your json file into a struct with a field for every string.

```rust
#![feature(lazy_cell)]

use std::sync::LazyLock;
use std::fs::File;
use serde_derive::{Serialize, Deserialize};

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct Strings {
    string1: String,
    string2: String,
}

static STRINGS: LazyLock<Strings> = LazyLock::new(|| {
    serde_json::from_reader(File::open("strings.json").unwrap()).unwrap()
});

fn main() {
    let string1: &'static str = &STRINGS.string1; //yep still 'static
    println!("{}", string1);
    //Strings.string2 has been lazily loaded
}
```

Comment: This sounds like the way forward, or at minimum has all the pieces I need. Thanks!